# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method getMaximumWindowMetrics()Landroid/view/WindowMetrics when retrieving android screen vieport size

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to set the image background based on the height and width of the viewport in android. I am using windowManager and receiving this error on a non-emulator device. I don't know if that has anything to do with it. The image is a splashscreen which I am trying to make responsive based on different viewport sizes. I found the windowManager.maximumWindowMetrics.bounds.height() to work well on the emulator devices but on a couple physical phones, I got this error below.  Here is the error

```
2021-10-29 15:17:56.184 30160-30160/com.example.appName E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.appName, PID: 30160
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method getMaximumWindowMetrics()Landroid/view/WindowMetrics; in class Landroid/view/WindowManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.view.WindowManager' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)
        at com.example.appName.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3101)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3264)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1955)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

Here is the code for the activity:

```
package com.example.appName

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.DisplayMetrics
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var constraintLayout: ConstraintLayout
    private lateinit var displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout)

        val height = windowManager.maximumWindowMetrics.bounds.height()
        var width = windowManager.maximumWindowMetrics.bounds.width()
        Log.i("MainActivity", "$height\n")
        Log.i("MainActivity", "$width\n")

        when{
            width in 1075..1085 && height in 2155..2165-> {
                constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splashscreen_1080x2160)
            }
            width in 1075..1085 && height in 2215..2225 -> {
                constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splashscreen_1080x2220)
            }
            width in 1075..1085 && height in 2275..2285-> {
                constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splashscreen_1080x2280)
            }
            width in 1275..1285 && height in 1915..1925-> {
                constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splashscreen_1280x1920)
            }
            width in 1435..1445 && height in 2555..2565 -> {
                constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splashscreen_1440x2560)
            }
            width in 1435..1445 && height in 2875..2885 -> {
                constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splashscreen_1440x2880)
            }
            width in 1435..1445 && height in 2955..2965 -> {
                constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splashscreen_1440x2960)
            }
            width in 1435..1445 && height in 3035..3045 -> {
                constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splashscreen_1440x3040)
            }
            else -> {
                constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splashscreen_1280x1920)
            }
        }


        android.os.Handler().postDelayed({
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, HomeActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }, 3500)
        }

}
```

Comment: What Android version is installed on the physical phones? What is your target SDK and min SDK versions specified in `build.gradle`?

Comment: ```minSdkVersion 21``` and ```targetSdkVersion 30``` in the app. the phone that i am getting the error on is android version 9 so I think API 29 or 28? i should also say that the emulator that it does work on is pixel 2 api 30 in android studio

Comment: `getMaximumWindowMetrics()` was added in SDK 30, so lint should be preventing you from compiling if your min version is less than 30. Have you disabled lint?

Comment: I plan to work with minimum SDK version of 21 or 24, so should I not use ```getMaximumWindowMetrics()``` at all? i will find out how to disable lint

Comment: i disabled it with ```lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }``` 
But  I get the exact same error.

Comment: I was saying disabling it is one possible way you could have created this problem. It’s definitely not my recommendation to disable lint! Lint should have shown an error because you can’t use new methods that don’t exist on older versions of Android down to your min SDK version. It would prevent you from compiling your code. You should use WindowCompat to work with window dimensions. It will properly delegate to functions that are available based on the version of Android it’s running on.

Comment: yea i re-enabled lint. seems like the thing you should not disable. i will use windowcompat. my question is, when things deprecate and the newer methods are introduced on newer APIs, how do you support the older APIs? are you forced to use deprecated methods?